# Getting the "Cannot extract the Status code from a result of type play.api.mvc.AsyncResult" even when result type has been converted to Result

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.0.3 (Java) and have written following code.  As my actor is async, I try to convert the AsyncResult to Result type when testing by doing as follows:

```
    Result result = new Result() { 
        @Override 
        public play.api.mvc.Result getWrappedResult() {
            return ((play.api.mvc.AsyncResult) callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Dashboard.index(),
                    authenticatedFakeRequest(lenderUser.getId())).getWrappedResult()).result().await().get();
        }
    };

    assertThat(Integer.valueOf(status(result)), is(Integer.valueOf(OK)));
```

This code does work in another set of tests I wrote, but when I use it in this particular case, it throws following runtime exception.  I am completely clueless why it worked for other tests and not here.  I have checked that instance type of result before it goes to above statement is of type Result and not AsyncResult.  I'd appreciate help with that as I am new to Play and cannot find answer on its google group.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot extract the Status code from a result of type play.api.mvc.AsyncResult
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor$.getStatus(JavaResults.scala:38)
at play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getStatus(JavaResults.scala)
at play.test.Helpers.status(Helpers.java:122)
at functional.controllers.LenderDashboardTest.dashboardPageHasNoControlsToAccessOtherTeamMembersInboxes(LenderDashboardTest.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across the same problem as you, and it seems updating Play to 2.1 has solved it for me. hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks but upgrading is not an option for me as it will require a lengthy procedure to get this signed off.